# Visual Basic 2012: I want something like a boolean but there are three possible answers?

Tags: vb.net

Visual Basic 2012: I want something like a boolean but there are three possible answers? Is there anything like this already or can you make something like this?

Comment: Did you check [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `DonA`'s answer, I'd recommend an `Enum`, however... I highly recommend using `-1`, `0`, and `1`.

```
Public Enum State
    FirstState = -1
    SecondState = 0
    ThirdState = 1
End Enum
```

Now you're not just using three values, but better, you're using three signs essentially.  Positive, zero, and negative.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `Enum`.

```
Public Enum Choices
  One
  Two
  Three
End Enum
```

Comment: True, False, FileNotFound  :)

Answer (score 0):

Really isn't necessary the generation of a new Enumeration... you could use [TriState Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.tristate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

An example:

```
Private Shadows Sub Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox(func(100)) ' Result = -2
End Sub

Public Function func(ByVal number As Integer) As TriState

    Select Case number

        Case Is < 100
            Return TriState.False

        Case Is > 100
            Return TriState.True

        Case Else ' Equals to 100
            Return TriState.UseDefault

    End Select

End Function
```